# Large matrix multiplication with low memory usage in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, out-of-memory, matrix-multiplication

I have a complex matrix multiplication with several hundreds of thousands of rows and columns. At some point the memory usage grows to 100% and then the computer is freezed and I have to restart it manually.

I have tried with Numba (writing the code inside a function with a decorator) and Dask (transforming the numpy arrays as da.from_array(var, chunk)) without success. I am not an expert in any of those.

I have read plenty of similar questions to this without finding a good solution for my problem.

A minimum reproducible example could be

```
m = 100000
n = 100000
a1 = np.random.rand(m)
a2 = np.random.rand(n)
c = np.random.rand(m)+1j*np.random.rand(m)
b = np.random.rand(n)+1j*np.random.rand(n)
A = np.exp(1j*np.outer(a1,a2))
d = c*np.dot(A,b)
```

What would be the best option of solving it in terms of memory usage? (not neccesarily the fastest)

Comment: `np.einsum` is much more memory efficient.

Comment: @MSS, more efficient than the `dot`?  are you sure?  But what about making A`?  That  makes several (m,n) buffers.

Comment: do you have space for one (n.m) complex array?

Comment: It might work to split the `m` dimension into batches and iterate on them

Comment: @MSS `np.einsum` is only useful to compute `c*np.dot(A,b)`. It cannot be used to build `A` which is clearly the main bottleneck here because of its very huge size (`100_000x100_000`). Thus, `np.einsum` is unfortunately nearly useless here. Even if it would be useful, the fastest path just call BLAS library internally like `np.dot` does (but more directly).

Comment: Thanks for making me understand hpaulj and Richard. Appreciate your time and efforts to write such good answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Main issue

The main issue is that `1j*np.outer(a1,a2)` takes `100_000 * 100_000 * (8 * 2) = 149 GiB`. On top of that, `np.exp` needs to read this matrix and produce another one of the same size so you need at least ~300 GiB of RAM just for this. This is HUGE and inefficient.

You should **avoid creating the matrix `A` at any price** (including similar temporary matrices).

---

### Fast memory-efficient solution

Numba can help in this case : you can compute the array `d` on the fly avoiding huge temporary matrices. Here is an optimized Numba code doing this:

```py
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit('(float64[::1], float64[::1], complex128[::1], complex128[::1])', parallel=True)
def compute(a1, a2, b, c):
    m, n = a1.size, a2.size
    assert n == m  # seems already mantatory in the initial code
    tmpDot = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.complex128)
    for i in nb.prange(n):
        for j in range(n):
            tmpDot[i] += np.exp(1j * (a2[j] * a1[i])) * b[j]
    return c * tmpDot

m = 100000
n = 100000
a1 = np.random.rand(m)
a2 = np.random.rand(n)
c = np.random.rand(m)+1j*np.random.rand(m)
b = np.random.rand(n)+1j*np.random.rand(n)
d = compute(a1, a2, b, c)
```

This code only take a very small amount of memory compared to the initial one : only few MiB. So it takes about **100_000 times less memory**! Besides, I also expect it to run significantly faster (because it is multi-threaded and better use the CPU caches as well as the RAM). It takes only 17.1 seconds on my machine (while I cannot even run the initial code)!

Answer (score 1):

Estimate memory uses:

```
m float64  # a1 = np.random.rand(m)
n float64  # a2 = np.random.rand(n)
m complex128   # c = np.random.rand(m)+1j*np.random.rand(m)
n complex   #b = np.random.rand(n)+1j*np.random.rand(n)
```

The b,c lines will have several complex temporary arrays, but end up with one each.

```
(m,n) complex   # A = np.exp(1j*np.outer(a1,a2))
```

`outer` makes a (m,n) complex; `1j*` makes another; `exp` another

Could try

```
A = np.zeros((m,n), dtype=complex)
np.outer(1j*a1,a2, out=A)
np.exp(A, out=A)
```

and finally:

```
m complex    # d = c*np.dot(A,b)
```

`dot` does (m,n) with (n,) => (m,).  Might make this more compact with

```
np.multiply(np.dot(A,b), c, out=c))
```

`dot` takes an `out`, but I don't have a free `(m,) complex`.

These uses of `out` might save some memory, eliminating some (m,n)complex temporary buffers.  Maybe even save a bit of time.